# custom syntax highlighting [JS]

Tags: notepad++

I would like to create custom syntax highlighting for

```
chrome.storage.local.get
chrome.i18n
chrome.runtime.sendMessage
//etc...
```

and to keep defined coloring for keywords, so that those custom ones stick out in some different color (eg. bluish).
So far I only manage to add [my words to KEYWORDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JxLk.png), but in that case, color is the same like the [rest of the keywords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58mUf.png).
So how to create my own syntax highlighting for custom keywords?
language: JavaScript
theme from SS: Waher-style

Answer (score 0):

I got answer on N++ forum.
Basically, this is not possible for Javascript language syntax
[more info](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11561/custom-syntax-highlighting-js)